# Reading record from a text file into array in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

1.this is my code i want to read a record from a text file into array in pascal my program is about making a hotel helper and i already have a text file with the data of the hotel then i should read it from the text file and store it in array .. but i am facing error 103 exit code (file not open).... any help Please . :)

### program Hotel1(input,output);

```
const  max =10;  MaxFloor =10;
type
Date = record
        day :1..31;
        month:1..12;
        year:integer;
       end;


Booking = record
           Guest:string[20];
           S_Date:date;
           E_date:date;
          end;


Booking_Mat= array[1..max] of Booking;

History_Booking = record
                   B_num:integer;
                   B_Mat:Booking_Mat;
                  end;

Room = record
        Num:integer;
        Bed_num:integer;
        Price:integer;
        Status:Boolean;
        H:History_Booking;
       end;

Data = record
       Ro:Room;
       m:integer;
       end;

Data_mat= array [1..max] of Data;



Procedure  Read_Data(filename:string; var table:Data_mat);
 var   df:text; i,j :integer;
  n,m,num,GN:integer;
  Bed_num,Price:integer;
  f:text;
  s,e:Date;
  Gname:string[20];
  ok:boolean;
  a:Data_mat;
 c:char;
 Begin
 writeln('Reading ',filename,' records into array.... ');
 assign(df,filename);
 reset(df);
i:=0;
   while (not eof) do
     begin
        i:=i+1;
         Read (f,num);
         a[i].Ro.num:=num;
         Read (f,Bed_num);
         a[i].Ro.Bed_num:=Bed_num;
         Read (f,Price);
      a[i].Ro.Price:=Price;
         Read(f,c);
          if (c ='Y') then
           a[i].Ro.status:= true
       else
           a[i].Ro.status:= false;

      readln;

  End; {while eof}
  close(df);
End; {Read_Data}
```

Comment: in the Main program i am just calling the procedure (Read_Data)

Comment: Loong Time since I did this, but shouldn't it Read have df as it's first argument, that's your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared two variables of type `Text`, (`df` and `f`) in your `var` block.

You open `df` with these lines:

```
assign(df,filename);
reset(df);
```

You then read from `f` (which is **not** the file you opened above) in several lines, such as this one:

```
Read (f, num);
```

It's interesting to note that you actually manage to close the file you really opened, even though you never use it in your loop:

```
close(df);
```

The solution to all of these issues is to delete the declaration of either `f` or `df`, and then fix the compiler errors you get by correcting the code to use the remaining `text` variable. (Two important lessons here are

1. Only declare the variables you actually need.
2. Use the variables you declare.

Your loop is also invalid, because you're using `while not eof` with no file provided for which to test the end. Your loop should read `while not Eof(df) do` instead.

It's also much better to follow the typical naming convention of prefixing types with a `T`. It makes it clear that it's a type and not a variable, and allows you to read the code more easily. For instance, I'd change your definition of `Data` to `TRoomData`, and change the other type declarations accordingly. Here's an example - note that `TRoomData` now has a field (member) named `Room` of type `TRoom`:

```
TRoomData = record
  Room: TRoom;
  m: Integer;
end;
```

`TRoom` is defined as

```
TRoom = record
  Num: Integer;
  Bed_num: Integer;
  Price: Integer;
  Status: Boolean;
  H: THistory_Booking;
end;
```

And so forth. This allows you to write code more clearly:

```
var
  RoomData: TRoomData;
begin
  RoomData.Room.Num := 1;
  RoomData.Room.Price := 50;
  // etc.
end;
```

With all that being said, your file does not contain `text`, and therefore you're using the wrong file type by using `df: Text` in the first place. You should use a `File of TRoomData`, allowing you to read and write entire records at a time. Here's an example of doing so:

```
var
  DF: File of TRoomData;
  RoomData: TRoomData;
  i: Integer;
const
  DataFileName = 'D:\TempFiles\RoomData.dat';
```

Writing it:

```
// Put some data into the record
RoomData.Room.Num := 1;
RoomData.Room.Bed_num := 1;
RoomData.Room.Price := 40;
RoomData.Room.Status := True;
RoomData.Room.H.B_num := 1;
for i := 1 to Max do
begin
  RoomData.Room.H.B_Mat[1].Guest := Format('Guest %d', [i]);
  RoomData.Room.H.B_Mat[1].S_Date.Year := 2014;
  RoomData.Ro.H.B_Mat[1].S_Date.Month := i;
  RoomData.Ro.H.B_Mat[1].S_Date.Day := i;
end;

// Write it out to the file
AssignFile(DF, DataFileName);
try
  Rewrite(DF);
  Write(DF, RoomData);
finally
  CloseFile(DF);
end;
```

Reading it back in:

```
AssignFile(DF, DataFileName);
try
  Reset(DF);
  Read(DF, RoomData);
finally
  CloseFile(DF);
end;
```

(Or, better yet: If the version of Pascal you're using supports it, move away from the old file I/O routines and start using `TFileStream` instead.)

Last but not least, *learn to properly format your code*. It makes it much easier to debug and maintain, and it's much easier to read when you can follow the execution path clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your advices @KenWhite i'll try to follow it .... but i declare 'DF' as text not 'file of text' so i have it the hard disk and i edit the file by a text editor (notepad) i mean i don't have to put data in my file the data is already exist in the file so i should read RoomData from the file and store it in array to use it in my program  .... my version of pascal doesn't support this

Comment: i have to use DF: text i wish i could do it with binary file it's gonna be easier but i am obligate to use text

Comment: Well, the first 9 or 10 paragraphs of my answer explain to you how to fix your code to work for that, if that's what you must do.